# Recycler view swaps items when i scroll them

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing the chatbot app. I am using the RecycleView to render the chat of user and bot. I have to show the user listview or text response depend upon his query. All is working until my RecyclerView get's scroll. Whenever my RecyclerView gets scroll it changes the item position. I search a lot and applied every solution but not able to solve my issue.

here is my activity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener, 
View.OnClickListener {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ChatAdapter mAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList;
private EditText inputMessage;
private RelativeLayout btnSend;
Boolean flagFab = true;
PaytmPGService service = null;
Map<String, String> paytmparam = new HashMap<>();
PrefManager prefManager;
private AIService aiService;
AIDataService aiDataService;
AIRequest aiRequest;
Gson gson;
String food_dish = " ";
double price = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);

    inputMessage = findViewById(R.id.editText_ibm);
    btnSend = findViewById(R.id.addBtnibm);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_ibm);

    messageArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this,messageArrayList);

    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);

            int msgCount = mAdapter.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (msgCount - 1) &&
                            lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);

            }

        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    this.inputMessage.setText("");

    final AIConfiguration configuration = new AIConfiguration("cabc4b7b9c20409aa7ffb1b3d5fe1243",
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

    aiService = AIService.getService(this, configuration);
    aiService.setListener(this);

    aiDataService = new AIDataService(configuration);

    aiRequest = new AIRequest();

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

    inputMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ImageView fab_img = findViewById(R.id.fab_img_ibm);
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_send_white_24dp);
            Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_mic_white_24dp);


            if (s.toString().trim().length() != 0 && flagFab) {
                ImageViewAnimatedChange(HomeActivity.this, fab_img, img);
                flagFab = false;

            } else if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                ImageViewAnimatedChange(HomeActivity.this, fab_img, img1);
                flagFab = true;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

}

public void ImageViewAnimatedChange(Context c, final ImageView v, final Bitmap new_image) {
    final Animation anim_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.zoom_out);
    final Animation anim_in  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.zoom_in);
    anim_out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            v.setImageBitmap(new_image);
            anim_in.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
            });
            v.startAnimation(anim_in);
        }
    });
    v.startAnimation(anim_out);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    final String inputmessage = this.inputMessage.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!inputmessage.equals("")){
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, AIResponse>(){

            private AIError aiError;

            @Override
            protected AIResponse doInBackground(final String... params) {
                final AIRequest request = new AIRequest();
                String query = params[0];


                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query))
                    request.setQuery(query);
                try {
                    return aiDataService.request(request);
                } catch (final AIServiceException e) {
                    aiError = new AIError(e);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final AIResponse response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    onResult(response);
                } else {
                    onError(aiError);
                }
            }
        }.execute(inputmessage);
    }else {
        aiService.startListening();
    }
    inputMessage.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onResult(AIResponse response) {
    int itemNumber = 0;
    Log.d("dialogeflow response",response.toString());
    try {
        JSONObject AIResponse = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(response));
        Log.d("json response",AIResponse.toString());
        final JSONObject result = AIResponse.getJSONObject("result");
        JSONArray contexts = result.getJSONArray("contexts");
        final JSONObject fulfillment = result.getJSONObject("fulfillment");
        if(contexts.length()>0) {
            for(int i = 0;i<contexts.length();i++) {
                JSONObject context_items = contexts.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject paramters = context_items.getJSONObject("parameters");
                if (paramters.has("Cuisine")) {
                    prefManager.setCuisinetype(paramters.getString("Cuisine"));
                } else if (paramters.has("Restaurants_name")) {
                    prefManager.setRestaurant_name(paramters.getString("Restaurants_name"));
                }
                if (paramters.has("number") && !paramters.getString("number").equals("") && paramters.has("Food_Dishes") && !paramters.getString("Food_Dishes").equals("")) {
                    itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(paramters.getString("number"));
                    if (itemNumber <= 2 && price !=0) {
                        price = 300 + (int) (Math.random() * ((1400 - 300) + 1));
                    } else {
                        price = 600 + (int) (Math.random() * ((2200 - 600) + 1));
                    }
                    food_dish = paramters.getString("Food_Dishes");
                }
            }
        }
        final double finalPrice = price;
        final int finalItemNumber = itemNumber;
        if(!result.getString("resolvedQuery").matches("payment is done successfully")) {
            Message usermsg = new Message();
            usermsg.setMessage(result.getString("resolvedQuery"));
            usermsg.setId("1");
            messageArrayList.add(usermsg);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (fulfillment.has("speech")) {
                Log.d("response of speech", fulfillment.getString("speech"));
                if (!fulfillment.getString("speech").equals("") && fulfillment.getString("speech") != null) {
                    final String speech = fulfillment.getString("speech");
                    if (fulfillment.getString("speech").matches("Redirecting you to the Pay-Tm site")) {
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Message outMessage = new Message();
                                outMessage.setMessage(speech);
                                outMessage.setId("2");
                                messageArrayList.add(outMessage);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                getpaytm_params((int) price);
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    } else {
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Message outMessage = new Message();
                                if (speech.contains("Your total bill is ₹")) {
                                    Log.d("price", String.valueOf(price));
                                    outMessage.setMessage("Please Confirm your order:- \n" +finalItemNumber +" "+food_dish+" from "+prefManager.getRestaurant_name()+" at Flat No: 20,Galaxy Apartment,Airport Authority Colony,Andheri,Mumbai,Maharashtra 400 047 \n Your total bill is ₹"+price+". \n Do you want to pay by Wallet or by PayTm");
                                }else{
                                    outMessage.setMessage(speech);
                                }
                                outMessage.setId("2");
                                messageArrayList.add(outMessage);
                                Log.d("messgae",outMessage.getMessage());
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                } else {
                    final JSONArray msg = fulfillment.getJSONArray("messages");
                    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            Message outMessage = new Message();
                            JSONObject speechobj = msg.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray speech = speechobj.getJSONArray("speech");
                            Log.d("response of speech", speech.getString(0));
                            outMessage.setMessage(speech.getString(0));

                            outMessage.setId("2");
                            messageArrayList.add(outMessage);
                        } else {
                            final int itemposition = i;
                            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Message outMessage = new Message();
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject speechobj = msg.getJSONObject(itemposition);
                                        JSONArray speech = speechobj.getJSONArray("speech");
                                        Log.d("response of speech", speech.getString(0));
                                        outMessage.setMessage(speech.getString(0));
                                        outMessage.setId("2");
                                        messageArrayList.add(outMessage);
                                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 5000);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (!fulfillment.getString("speech").equals("") && fulfillment.getString("speech") != null) {
                final String speech = fulfillment.getString("speech");
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Message outMessage = new Message();
                            outMessage.setMessage(speech);
                            outMessage.setId("2");
                            messageArrayList.add(outMessage);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    },2000);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onError(AIError error) {

}

@Override
public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

}

@Override
public void onListeningStarted() {
    btnSend.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.recording_bg));
}

@Override
public void onListeningCanceled() {
    btnSend.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.stedy_recording));
}

@Override
public void onListeningFinished() {
    btnSend.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.stedy_recording));
}
}`
```

my ChatAdapter.java class

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private int BOT = 100;
private int BOT_Restaurant_ListView = 101;
private int USER = 102;
private Activity activity;
private PrefManager prefManager;
private int itemposition = -1;
private int menu_itemposition = -1;
private List<Restaurant_List_Model> restaurant_list;
private ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList;
private RestaurantListViewAdapter restaurantListViewAdapter;
private TextToSpeech tts ;

public ChatAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.messageArrayList = messageArrayList;
    tts = new TextToSpeech(activity, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            }
        }
    });
    prefManager = new PrefManager(activity.getApplicationContext());
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemview;

    if(viewType == BOT){
        itemview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bot_msg_view,parent,false);
    }else if(viewType == BOT_Restaurant_ListView){
        itemview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bot_msg_restaurant_listview,parent,false);
    }else {
        itemview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_msg_view,parent,false);
    }

    return new ViewHolder(itemview);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
    if(message.getId()!=null && message.getId().equals("2")){
        if(message.getMessage().contains("restaurants") || message.getMessage().contains("restaurant")) {
            return BOT_Restaurant_ListView;
        }else {
            return BOT;
        }
    }else{
        return USER;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int pic_int = 1;
    String filename = null;
    final Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
    message.setMessage(message.getMessage());
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == BOT_Restaurant_ListView) {
        Log.d("inside bot listview msg", String.valueOf(BOT_Restaurant_ListView ));
        Log.d("adapter position", String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        if(itemposition<holder.getAdapterPosition()){
            itemposition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            Log.d("itemposition",String.valueOf(itemposition));
            String jsonFileContent;
            Log.d("cuisine value", prefManager.getCuisinetype());
            if (message.getMessage().contains("restaurants")) {
                if(!prefManager.getCuisinetype().equals("") && prefManager.getCuisinetype() != null){
                    Log.d("restauratn has drawn", "greate");
                    try {
                        restaurant_list = new ArrayList<>();
                        restaurantListViewAdapter = new RestaurantListViewAdapter(activity, restaurant_list);
                        ((ViewHolder) holder).retaurant_listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ((ViewHolder) holder).retaurant_listView.setAdapter(restaurantListViewAdapter);
                        Log.d("cuisine value", prefManager.getCuisinetype());
                        if(message.getMessage().contains("Here are restaurants near you")){
                            String [] restaurant_Array ={
                                    "indian","french","mexican","italian"
                            };
                            int randomNumber = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*restaurant_Array.length);
                            filename = restaurant_Array[randomNumber];
                            Log.d("filename",filename);
                            jsonFileContent = readFile(activity.getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "raw", activity.getPackageName()));
                        }else {
                            filename = prefManager.getCuisinetype().toLowerCase() + "_restaurants";
                            Log.d("filename", filename);
                            jsonFileContent = readFile(activity.getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "raw", activity.getPackageName()));
                        }
                        JSONObject restaurantfile = new JSONObject(jsonFileContent);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = restaurantfile.getJSONArray("restaurants");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            ImageRoundCorner imageRoundCorner = new ImageRoundCorner();
                            JSONObject restaurantList = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Restaurant_List_Model restaurant_list_obj = new Restaurant_List_Model();
                            restaurant_list_obj.setName(restaurantList.getString("name"));
                            restaurant_list_obj.setLocation(restaurantList.getString("location"));
                            restaurant_list_obj.setImage_of_item(imageRoundCorner.getRoundedCornerBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), activity.getResources().getIdentifier("restaurant_" + pic_int, "drawable", activity.getPackageName()))));
                            pic_int++;
                            restaurant_list_obj.setRating(restaurantList.getLong("rating"));

                            restaurant_list.add(restaurant_list_obj);
                        }

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            tts.speak(message.getMessage(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                        } else {
                            tts.speak(message.getMessage(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }
                        prefManager.setCuisinetype("");
                        pic_int = 1;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    restaurantListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


            }else if(message.getMessage().contains("Here are some famous food items from "+prefManager.getRestaurant_name()+" restaurant")){
                try {
                    Log.d("menu has draw","greate");
                    restaurant_list = new ArrayList<>();
                    restaurantListViewAdapter = new RestaurantListViewAdapter(activity, restaurant_list);
                    ((ViewHolder) holder).retaurant_listView.setAdapter(restaurantListViewAdapter);
                    ((ViewHolder) holder).retaurant_listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.d("restaurant name value", prefManager.getRestaurant_name());
                    jsonFileContent = readFile(R.raw.restaurant_menu);
                    JSONObject menu_cuisine = new JSONObject(jsonFileContent);
                    ImageRoundCorner imageRoundCorner = new ImageRoundCorner();
                    if (menu_cuisine.has(prefManager.getRestaurant_name())) {
                        JSONObject restaurant_menu = menu_cuisine.getJSONObject("Dominos");
                        Log.d("Chili's American menu", restaurant_menu.toString());
                        JSONArray menu = restaurant_menu.getJSONArray("menu");
                        for (int j = 0; j < menu.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject menu_obj = menu.getJSONObject(j);
                            Restaurant_List_Model restaurant_list_obj = new Restaurant_List_Model();
                            restaurant_list_obj.setName(menu_obj.getString("name"));
                            restaurant_list_obj.setLocation(menu_obj.getString("cuisine_type"));
                            restaurant_list_obj.setImage_of_item(imageRoundCorner.getRoundedCornerBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), activity.getResources().getIdentifier("menu_" + pic_int, "drawable", activity.getPackageName()))));
                            //restaurant_list_obj.setImage_of_item(imageRoundCorner.getRoundedCornerBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), activity.getResources().getIdentifier("menu_" + pic_int, "drawable", activity.getPackageName()))));
                            pic_int++;
                            restaurant_list_obj.setRating(menu_obj.getLong("rating"));
                            restaurant_list.add(restaurant_list_obj);
                        }
                        restaurantListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            tts.speak(message.getMessage(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                        } else {
                            tts.speak(message.getMessage(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }
                        pic_int = 1;
                        prefManager.setRestaurant_name("");
                    }
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        Log.d("user_message",message.getMessage());
                        tts.speak(message.getMessage(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                    }else {
                        tts.speak(message.getMessage(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    }
                    pic_int = 1;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ((ViewHolder) holder).retaurant_listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                    }
                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    } if(holder.getItemViewType()==BOT) {
        Log.d("adapter position", String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        Log.d("inside bot msg", String.valueOf(BOT));
            ((ViewHolder) holder).bot_msg.setText(message.getMessage());
            if(itemposition<holder.getAdapterPosition()) {
                itemposition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    tts.speak(message.getMessage(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                } else {
                    tts.speak(message.getMessage(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
    }if(holder.getItemViewType() == USER) {
        ((ViewHolder) holder).user_message.setText(message.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    if(holder.isRecyclable()){
        Log.d("inside onViewRecycled","great");
       // itemposition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messageArrayList.size();
}

private String readFile(int id) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getResources().openRawResource(id)));

    String content = "";
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        content = content + line;
    }

    return content;

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView user_message,bot_msg;
    private ListView retaurant_listView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        bot_msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bot_message);
        user_message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        retaurant_listView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_items_list_ibm);

    }
}
}
```

Please help me out with this issue.
In gif, you can see the lower list is swap with the upper list and then return back

[image]